# Loading two Iframes is failing

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to load two iframes one on top of the other and i only see the top one visible

```
<iframe src ="http://www.videoapt.com/tabid/53/VPID/119/VP/AMLI7thStreetStation/Default.aspx" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"><br>
<iframe src ="http://www.circlepix.com/home3/LWAPPH" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the iframe.

`<iframe></iframe>`

It's not a self-closing element.